# Remotely run Windows 10 command line from Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-access, jenkins, windows-server-2016

I have Jenkins running a batch file on a Windows Server 2016 PC.

The batch file that Jenkins runs needs to execute a program, via command line, on a Windows 7 PC.  *This is part of an automated build process.*

Both Windows Server 2016 and Windows 7 PCs are connected on an internal network.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Windows and the PCs are on the same network, you should be able to leverage PowerShell's remote command functionality. It is [documented very well](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7) by Microsoft. You can even set up a script on your local PC (in this case the Windows Server) that will be run on the remote PC (the Windows 7 PC).

I have never used this feature myself, and it does admittedly seem a bit more complicated than SSH, but it should work well assuming you set it up properly (this [Remote Requirements document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7) should help).